# How to make multiple windows in a program

Tags: c#, window

I am fairly new to C#, but I'm trying to write a program. For said program, I need to have multiple windows inside of the ClientBounds.

http://videoproductiontips.com/video-editing/editing-computers-and-video-editing-software/

As you can see in the link, this program is split into several different sections that allow for different tasks.

I have looked all over, but I simply can't find a tutorial or example code for how to do this in C# or XNA.

Sorry if I used the wrong jargon, as I said, I'm new.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: say whether you use winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly all you need to do is to add a new form (right click on the project, add > new item > windows form (or something like that))

And then make a button in your original form and in his event type 
Form2 myform = new Form2();
myform.Show();

(when form2 is the name of your second form)

Comment: I don't think he is looking for a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link out as a starting point](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx).  You are looking for "Docking" windows. I'm assuming you're using WPF. If not, do a search for

> Docking Windows WinForms

for more information.

Comment: Hey Reed. Can you mark the question as answered so we can close this off.

Answer (score 0):

Docking is what you're looking for I think? If you're using WPF and searching for docking options, try [Avalon Dock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

It's open source and pretty easy to incorporate than most other docking libraries I've tried. In fact, I've used it and would recommend it too. :)